# Java Unisex Bathroom monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have to solve this problem by Monitor locks. I did some code but I need your advice with my logic. In output for example it seems like it checks only the case of 1 person is occupied the bathroom and the other one waiting for it turn  (I'm sorry for my english, I am trying to discribe as I can).
Here is the output:

`Man 0 enters bathroom 
Man 0 in bathroom 
Man 0 exits bathroom 
Man 0 enters bathroom 
Man 0 in bathroom 
Man 0 exits bathroom 
Woman 1 enters bathroom 
Woman 1 in bathroom 
Man 2 in waiting------------>>>>
Woman 1 exits bathroom 
Man 2 in bathroom 
Man 2 exits bathroom 
Woman 2 enters bathroom 
Woman 2 in bathroom 
Woman 2 exits bathroom`

And here is the code of 4 functions.

```
public void woman_wants_to_enter(int i) throws InterruptedException {

    lock.lock();
    try {

        if (occupiedCount < numberOfToilets) {

            if (menUsingN == 0) {

                if (womenWaitingN == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Woman " + i + " enters bathroom ");
                    womenUsingN++;
                    occupiedCount++;
                } else {
                    while (womenWaitingN != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Woman " + i + " in waiting------------>>>>");
                        womenWaitingN++;
                        womenWaitingQueue.await();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                while (menUsingN != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Woman " + i + " in waiting------------>>>>");
                    womenWaitingN++;
                    womenWaitingQueue.await();
                }
            }

        } else {
            while (occupiedCount == numberOfToilets) {
                System.out.println("Woman " + i + " in waiting------------>>>>");
                womenWaitingN++;
                womenWaitingQueue.await();
            }
        }

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void woman_leaves(int i) throws InterruptedException {

    lock.lock();
    try {

        womenUsingN--;
        occupiedCount--;
        System.out.println("Woman " + i + " exits bathroom ");

        if (womenWaitingN > 0) {
            womenWaitingQueue.signal();
            womenUsingN++;
            occupiedCount++;
            womenWaitingN--;
        } else if (menWaitingN > 0 && womenUsingN == 0) {
            menWaitingQueue.signal();
            menUsingN++;
            occupiedCount++;
            menWaitingN--;
        }

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

public void man_wants_to_enter(int i) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {

        if (occupiedCount < numberOfToilets) {

            if (womenUsingN == 0) {

                if (womenWaitingN > 0) {
                    womenWaitingQueue.signal();
                    womenUsingN++;
                    occupiedCount++;
                    womenWaitingN--;
                } else {
                    menUsingN++;
                    occupiedCount++;
                    System.out.println("Man " + i + " enters bathroom ");
                    menWaitingQueue.signal();
                }
            } else {
                while (womenUsingN != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Man " + i + " in waiting------------>>>>");
                    menWaitingN++;
                    menWaitingQueue.await();
                }
            }

        } else {
            while (occupiedCount == numberOfToilets) {
                System.out.println("Man " + i + " in waiting------------>>>>");
                menWaitingN++;
                menWaitingQueue.await();
            }
        }

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void man_leaves(int i) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {

        menUsingN--;
        occupiedCount--;
        System.out.println("Man " + i + " exits bathroom ");

        if (womenWaitingN > 0 && menUsingN == 0) {
            womenWaitingQueue.signal();
            womenUsingN++;
            occupiedCount++;
            womenWaitingN--;
        } else if (menWaitingN > 0) {
            menWaitingQueue.signal();
            menWaitingN--;
            menUsingN++;
            occupiedCount++;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate for your advice
BTW the numberOfToilets=3;

```
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition womenWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();
private Condition menWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();

private int womenWaitingN = 0;
private int menWaitingN = 0;
private int womenUsingN = 0;
private int menUsingN = 0;
private int numberOfToilets;
private int occupiedCount;

public BathRoom(int numberOfToilets, int occupiedCount) {
    this.numberOfToilets = numberOfToilets;
    this.occupiedCount = occupiedCount;
}
```

Main function

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    Thread[] women = new Thread[3];
    Thread[] men = new Thread[3];
    int numberOfToilets = 3;
    int occupiedCount = 0;
    BathRoom theBathRoom = new BathRoom(numberOfToilets, occupiedCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        women[i] = new Thread(new Woman(i, theBathRoom));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        men[i] = new Thread(new Man(i, theBathRoom));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        women[i].start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        men[i].start();
}
```

Woman class

```
class Woman implements Runnable {
private int n; /* This identifies the woman. */
private BathRoom theBathRoom;

public Woman(int n, BathRoom b) {
    this.n = n;
    this.theBathRoom = b;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        try {
            theBathRoom.woman_wants_to_enter(n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Woman " + n + " in bathroom ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        try {
            theBathRoom.woman_leaves(n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
Man class

```
class Man implements Runnable {
private int n; /* this identifies the man */
private BathRoom theBathRoom;

public Man(int n, BathRoom b) {
    this.n = n;
    this.theBathRoom = b;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        try {
            theBathRoom.man_wants_to_enter(n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Man " + n + " in bathroom ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (500 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        try {
            theBathRoom.man_leaves(n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have added 1 more Thread.sleep to keep them staying in bathroom and seems to be no problem in code.Anyway if someone would like to test it and maybe give me any tip about any kind of problem I'll appreciate to him.

Comment: You may need to show us the code that calls these functions.

Comment: So I added the rest of the code

Comment: Try running it with a larger number of iterations - say 30 rather than 3 for each thread - and provide the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that men and women should not enter the bathroom at the same time. So it seams to work fine if persons of different gender want to enter. Try if it's working if several person of same gender want to enter the bathroom.

Comment: The problem I can't catch in output the case when 1 person is in, without exiting, and the other one(of the same gender) is trying to enter.Mostly it looks like this...... Woman 1 enters bathroom 
Woman 1 in bathroom 
Woman 1 exits bathroom 
Woman 0 enters bathroom 
Woman 0 in bathroom 
Woman 0 exits bathroom